# Create a upload button in PyQt QGIS plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt4

I want to create 2 upload file button in PyQt.
One for image and one for .csv file.
If the uploaded file is not in image or .csv file it should thrown an message.

I have search a lot on internet and in internet but couldn't find answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the uploaded file is not in image or .csv file it should thrown an
>   message.

It is not the most common approach I think.

The best way to do this is to create a file dialog, that allows to choose only one extension. Example:

```
def upload_csv(self):
    dialog = QtGui.QFileDialog()
    fname = dialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Import CSV", "", "CSV data files (*.csv)")
```

Then just connect this function to any button you want. File dialog appears each time you click on it and you can choose only csv file. You can combine more extensions in one dialog if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, could you please explain me how to link function to dialog box in PyQt?

Comment: Could you please show one example, actually I am new to it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just create a button and connect this function like that: `self.dlg.button.clicked.connect(self.upload_csv)` then each time you clikc you'll see a dialog. When you choose a file and click 'ok', file path will be stored in `fname` variable (3rd line) and you can use it to read this file.

Comment: Thanks it's working, one more small help can't I through an message if it's closed without selecting a file?

Comment: If you close without selecting a file `fname` is equal to `None`. So you can put there a conditional statement `if fname: # do something`